# Is this a sufficient condition for Lebesgue-measurability?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be Lebesgue measurable sets such that $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $C\cap A$ and $C\cap B$ are measurable. Is this last condition a sufficient condition for $C$ to be measurable?

I suppose it is, as $(C\cap A)\cup (C\cap B)=C$, as $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and the finite union of measurable sets is evidently measurable. Nevertheless, I want to confirm my thoughts, as I don't know If I am missing something.

Thanks in advanced!

**My definition of Lebesgue Measure:** Firstly, it can be proved that any open set can be expressed as the union of disjoint diadic cubes, which their closure is contained in the open set (I don't prove it, but this decomposition always exists). Due to this, I define the measure of an open set $G\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $m(G)$, as the sum of the volumes of the intervals in the previously commented decomposition. Then, on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, I define the outer Lebesgue measure, $\lambda^{*}$, which I define as following: given $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $\lambda^{*}(A)=\inf\{m(G): G\textrm{ is open}, A\subseteq G\}$. Then, defining that $A$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set if, given $\epsilon >0$, $\exists G$ open set and $\exists F$ closed set such that $F\subseteq A\subseteq G$ and $m(G\setminus F)<\epsilon$, I verify that the subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ formed by the Lebesgue-measurable sets, which I call $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, is a $\sigma$- algebra. Then, the Lebesgue (positive) measure, $\lambda$, is just the restriction of $\lambda^{*}$ to $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Comment: Your proof of measurabilty of $C$ is perfect. Why do you doubt that?

Comment: Okey! Thanks... I don't know, It seemed so obvious I was doubting of my proof. Thank you so much for answering!